# Does hooks simplify your code or is just a matter of taste?

Tags: reactjs

Particularly speaking about state  I've been playing around with hooks and honestly I don't see many benefits comparing to class components. It is said that a benefit is that you can add state to a function component when required in the future but to me transforming into a class is not a big deal.

Comment: you mean transforming your current code base that mostly builds on classes based components is not a big deal, well yes!

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean when you write a new component that is stateless. It's not a big deal turning it into a Class component.

Comment: but that does not indecates thats the hooks are useless since they are out and I'm using them and they are much much better at lease their effect on my mindset and how I approach building things!

Comment: oh ok,I'm sorry I missed read you.
if your components no complicated and flat then yes it's not a big deal but in some cases, this change could break the component,eventually as you expressed before we as developers we approach building things the way we like, dont' we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why Hooks ?

**Without hooks you can’t reuse stateful logic between components**

- you may be familiar with patterns like render-props and HOCs that try to solve this.
- But these patterns require you to restructure your components
- Hooks allow you to reuse stateful logic without changing your component hierarchy.

**Life cycles are weird**

- Related code gets split apart, but completely unrelated code ends up combined in a single lifecycle method
- Hooks let you split unrelated pieces apart and group related pieces together in one function

**Classes are not cool**

- Too much code, yuck!
- Have to bind event handlers
- Have to understand how ‘this’ works

Comment: what about component testing? I heard that it's really difficult to mock dependencies

Comment: @PatoLoco sometimes people say it's hard, but it's because they don't know enough or haven't learn yet. At the begging, it's dificult

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the benefits using hooks, taken from the React's documentation.

> 1. Hooks allow you to reuse stateful logic without changing your
>      component hierarchy. This makes it easy to share Hooks among many
>      components or with the community.

With Hooks you can reuse your API calls and make your code more usable, which leads to less time spent on rewriting your expected behaviour.

> 2. Hooks let you split one component into smaller functions based on what pieces are related (such as setting up a subscription or fetching
>      data), rather than forcing a split based on lifecycle methods. You may
>      also opt into managing the component’s local state with a reducer to
>      make it more predictable.

This makes your components more compact, which in turn makes your code more readable, which is what you would want to see in your everyday code.

> 3. Classes confuse both people and machines

In javascript `this` is not interpreted as the same as other languages and also whether to use classes or functional components confuse developers, why would you need to choose one if you can do everything functionally? Also for performance issues when folding the components **classes are not minimized as well as functions** and for React to stay relevant it should be optimized.